# Titanium appcelerator : Return more than 20 results at a time in JSON response in Google Places API

Tags: android, json, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I have used Google Api in order to retrive places details but Google Api only returns 20 results at a time according to category. JSON parsed text contains next_page_token which have referance that could be used to retrive another page containing results and so on. My question is how to put parsing in loop so that i can get all the total results.

Answer (score 1):

So you have to build up a list of all results, but not invoke your callback until all results are downloaded. In the code below, we keep calling the function to get the next page of results until the next_page_token isn't available, in which case we've loaded all results and can invoke our callback function.

```
var jsonresults = [];

function getPlacesResults(url, callback) {
    var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({...});
    xhr.onload = function (data) {
      var json = JSON.parse(data);
      jsonresults.push(json)
      if (json.next_page_token) {
        //assumes next_page_token is a url we can pass in
        getPlacesResults(json.next_page_token, callback);
      } else {
        callback(jsonresults);
      }
    }
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.send();
}


//used like so
getPlacesResults('http://www.google.com/whatever', function (allResults) {
  //...do stuff with all of your results here.
});
```